# Adding data to excel from text file using shell

Tags: shell

I have 2 outputs from below commands  (Using SHELL)

Output 1

```
bash-4.2$ cat job4.txt | cut -f2 -d ":" | cut -f1 -d "-"
Gathering Facts
 Upload the zipped binaries to repository
 Find the file applicatons in remote node
 Upload to repository
 include_tasks
 Check and create on  path if release directory exists
 change dir 
 include_tasks
 New release is unzipped 
 Starting release to unzip package delivered 
 Get the file contents
 Completed
Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 5 minutes, 51 seconds
```

Output 2

```
bash-4.2$ awk '{print $NF}' job4.txt
4.78s
2.48s
1.87s
0.92s
0.71s
0.66s
0.55s
0.44s
0.24s
0.24s
0.24s
0.03s
seconds
```

My actual output should be in excel. Like Output 1 should go to column 1 and Output 2 should go to column 2.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: `printf "%s %s\n" $(cut -f2 -d ":" job4.txt | cut -f1 -d "-")`

Comment: Last line of Output1  has commas. Can the commas be part of any line?

Comment: yes last line can be ignored, rest of the outputs will be printed in two columns

Comment: provide some sample inputs lines (at least 3) from `job4.txt` . And the corresponding output lines. The answer script is simple `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your output1 and output2 are in files file1.txt and file2.txt and last line of output1 can be ignored:

```
paste -d"," file1.txt file2.txt > mergedfile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

write the first out to a file . Similarly do it for 2nd one file as well.

cmd goes here > file1.txt

2ndcmd goes here > file2.txt

Then To merge files line by line, you can use the paste command. And you can use a delimiter "\t" as different and write to csv

paste file1.txt file2.txt > mergedfile.csv

Ref: https://geek-university.com/linux/merge-files-line-by-line/

Comment: I had used below command ```
paste -d "\t" file1.txt file2.txt > output.csv
```

Comment: But file1 and file2 is merged in a single cell. Not in different columns

Comment: Output1 and output2 are mergered but in csv it is displayed in a single cell. Need output 1 in column 1 and output2 in column 2

Comment: While opening the csv, you need to mention the delimiter as tab . So you will be able to see it in two columns Ref: https://www.atensoftware.com/p90.php?q=187